# How to retrieve specific set of values from the array of objects using linq

Tags: c#

I have one class as below:

```
public class test
{    
     int i;

     string str;

     Socket s;

     DateTime dt;
}
```

and am creating object of this class as below

```
public void collection()
{

   test t1=new test{i=1,str="string1", s=soc1, dt=DateTime.Today() };

   test t2=new test{i=2,str="string2", s=soc2, dt=DateTime.Today() };

   test t3=new test{i=3,str="string3", s=soc3, dt=DateTime.Today() };

   ArraList a=new ArrayList();

   a.Add(t1);

   a.Add(t2);

   a.Add(t3);

}
```

and am adding all these objects(`t1`,`t2`,`t3`) into an array. Now, how can i get all socket members in object array using linq???

Comment: How can you access private members outside class without reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should cast your ArrayList to a collection of type 'test'

so

```
a.Cast<test>.Select(t => t.s);
```

Will give you the result.

Or if you think your ArrayList might also contain other types of obejct, you can use

```
a.OfType<test>.Select(t => t.s);
```

Note: Make sure Socket is a publicly accessible property and depending on the framework you use, consider using a Generic collection

Comment: No it wont, remember `s` is private

Comment: Oops in that case either he needs have public Socket prop or try out reflection

Comment: Ya this works and sounds good. Now if am declaring one more collection  Hash-table and am initializing all 3 Hash-table objects with some values. Now how to get those collection values in all 3 hashtable using linq??

Comment: @RaghuSYadav, instead of HashTable use generic [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). Are you working on .Net framework 1.1 ?

Comment: Please use typed colelctions. If you really want to use Hashtable, then hashtable.Values.OfType<YourObjectType>() will work

Comment: Thanks Nasmi Sabeer. I tried above thing but its not working for Hash-table, may be am not getting your thought. Can you just explain me briefly

Comment: Hashtable is basically a dictionary where they key is an object and the value is also an object. So objects can be anything, coz everything in c# inherits from Object. Please post your problem in a separate question, also consider using Generic Dictionary<TKey, TValue>  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772831/what-is-the-generic-version-of-a-hashtable

Comment: ya you are rite and i got that. I dint get hashtable.Values.OfType<YourObjectType>(). This can be used to get all values in single  hashtable object, but i want to select all values in 3 objects(t1,t2,t3) object Hashtable into single variable.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get your question? How many HashTables you have in total, and what are the values you add into them

Comment: test t1 = new test { i = 1, str = "string1", s = soc, dt = DateTime.Today };
            t1.ht.Add(1,"hi");
            t1.ht.Add(2,"bye");
            test t2 = new test { i = 2, str = "string2", s = soc, dt = DateTime.Today };
            t2.ht.Add(3, "new");
            t2.ht.Add(4, "old");
            test t3 = new test { i = 3, str = "string3", s = soc, dt = DateTime.Today };
            t2.ht.Add(5, "how");
            t2.ht.Add(6, "when");

            List<test> a = new List<test>();
            a.Add(t1);
            a.Add(t2);
            a.Add(t3);

Comment: You must have continued this on a new post

Comment: now i have 3 objects of class test. Inside that test objects i have 3 hash-tables. So now how can i get all values n 3 hash-table???

Comment: Sorry  am new to Stackoverflow so may be my questions are bit incomplete Nasim Sabeer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: this should work  a.Select(x => x.ht.Values.OfType<String>()).SelectMany(v => v);     I still think your class design has room for improvments

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Generic List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead of ArrayList, if you are working on .Net framework 2.0 or above. *(You have to define your fields as public to be accessible outside the class)*

```
List<test> list = new List<test>();
list.Add(t1);
....
```

To get all items you can do:

```
var items = list.Select(r=> r.s).ToArray();
```

There are many other problems in your code. `DateTime.Today` is used like a method, whereas its just a property. If you want to use ArrayList then your classes and corrected code should be:

```
public class test
{
    public int i;
    public string str;
    public Socket s;
    public DateTime dt;
}


test t1 = new test { i = 1, str = "string1", s = soc1, dt = DateTime.Today };
test t2 = new test { i = 2, str = "string2", s = soc2, dt = DateTime.Today };
test t3 = new test { i = 3, str = "string3", s = soc3, dt = DateTime.Today };

ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
a.Add(t1);
a.Add(t2);
a.Add(t3);
```

To select sockets from the ArrayList

```
var items = a.Cast<test>().Select(r=> r.s).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way (this requires public properties of test):

```
var a = new List<test>()
{
    new test{i=1,str="string1", s=soc1, dt=DateTime.Today() },
    new test{i=2,str="string2", s=soc2, dt=DateTime.Today() },
    new test{i=3,str="string3", s=soc3, dt=DateTime.Today() }

};

var sockets = a.Select(t => t.s);
```